# How to get output of for-loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, input, output

I have written a code that prints all letters, but I want to take its output to put it in a variable. i.e. I want to take all letters and save it in one variable instead of writing all letters manually.

```
for letter in range(97, 123):
    letters = chr(letter)
    print(letters, end=" ")
```

Comment: Why not write them to a list?  What thoughts have you tried already?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to complete this in one line, Python has a neat way of allowing you to create lists with the use of `list comprehensions`. If you wish to know more about what a list comprehension is, you may see point 5.1.3 [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
letters = [chr(letter) for letter in range(97, 123)]
```

A more comprehensible way of solving the problem is to append the characters to a letters list which should be defined before you begin to loop your range.

```
letters = []
for letter in range(97, 123):
    letters.append(chr(letter))

print(letters)
```

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) does a good job of explaining the different data structures used throughout the programming language, I hope this clears up the various ways to solve your problem described.

Comment: Nice one.  Upvote for the diligent effort and referencing the docs.